# How can I make sure my health checks work in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm currently trying to add health checks into my API through my helm chart. However, when I run this service under kubernetes it seems that my pod is ready but I have 0/1 Running and when I try to hit the URL for the service is not returning anything.

This is how my deployment looks:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "test.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}

          readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: /health
                  port: 8001
                initialDelaySeconds: 60
                periodSeconds: 60

          livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /health
                port: 8001
              initialDelaySeconds: 60
              periodSeconds: 60
  
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8001
            failureThreshold: 60
            periodSeconds: 60

          env:
              {{- range .Values.variables }}
              - name: {{ .name }}
                value: {{ .value }}
              {{- end }} 
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80001
              protocol: TCP
```

If I delete the health checks, I will have 1/1 Running. Does anyone knows if I have to add something else to the health checks?

Comment: where there `0/1` running, describe the pod `kubectl describe pods pod_name` and at the bottom you will see why the check failing,  most probably the endpoint `/heatlcheck` may not returning status code `2xx`

Comment: or you can go inside the pod and do `curl -I localhost:80001/health`, it should return `2xx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your healthcheck specification looks syntactically fine.
But your port number seems wrong: The maximum possible TCP port is 65535, you specify 80001. Probably a zero too many?

Verify which port your application is listening to in the container and use that port.

You can verify it by running the app as local docker container and call the health check with curl.

Comment: Yeah, I added an extra 0 to my port and by doing that it will grab the vnet IP instead of the Kubernetes Service.